# Generating infinite index subgroups of a free group

Tags: gr.group-theory, free-groups

Let $F$ be nonabelian finitely generated free group, let $H \leq F$ be a finitely generated subgroup of infinite index and let $x,y \in F \setminus H$. Must there be some $a \in F$ such that $[F : \langle H,a,xay\rangle] = \infty$ ?

Comment: What is the motivation to this question? Though i admit, it's interesting on its own!

Comment: I can't think of a nice argument, so I delete my answer. I do have the feeling such an $a$ should always exist.

Comment: Perhaps Johan is right. My brain is damaged by semigroup theory, so may be the following does not make any sense: what if using those complexes related to any finite presentation and from which one gets a short proof of Nielsen-Schreier Theorem and Kurosh's Theorem? (I don't have Lyndon-Schupp now) -- it was about finding paths in that complex which does all the job, and it seems this could suit here

Comment: Another thing, this time even more vague, what if viewing this situation as inside the free inverse monoid -- we can work with elements there as the corresponding Munn trees -- do some combinatorial things to glue trees as we need -- and then project back onto the free group

Comment: You can always find a one-relator quotient into which H maps injectively  and properly and infinite index. Take a to be that relator.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: gassho, Master! It's crazy -- i've been doing one-relators a lot, and forgot about them and Frieheitssatz! It's really nice!!!

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: the moral of the story is not to be like Kyogen with his man on a tree from Mumonkan, koan number 5

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg I have two questions about your comment. First, I do not know why there is a one-relator quotient into which $H$ maps injectively and properly of infinite index. Second, I can't see why my subgroup is of infinite index in this case. Your choice of $a$ does not seem to depend on $x,y$ which raises some doubts.

Comment: I think the techniques of http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2000-128-11/S0002-9939-00-05508-8/ wee applicable but need to think. I didn't see x,y are chosen first.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg As we discussed with Pablo earlier, if say $x\in H$ then $y\in\langle H,a,xay\rangle$ but still it may be that $\langle H,y\rangle=F$

Comment: It says x,y are not in H.

Comment: But I agree xay and a have bad small cancellation properties. :(

Comment: They do have bad 'unbased' small cancellation properties, but this is a 'based' question. And as Ben's answer explains, we mostly just need to choose a so that it doesn't cancel too much with $x^{\pm1}$ and  $y^{\pm1}$.

Answer (score 2):

Taking the finite subgraph  of the Schreier graph contains the Stallings graph of H and x,y^{-1} read from the base point. Going to a conjugate we may assume some letter is not read at the base point. Choose a word a not readable on this finite graph and beginning with the letter not readable at the base and ending with the inverse of that letter. Then we can sow a at the base point and have a Stallings graph. Now sow a from the end of x to the end of y^{-1} and do Stallings folding. Because a cannot be read on the original graph the folds should not result in a covering space. I'll try later to write details later.

Comment: For which finitely generated groups that are not free could your argument (maybe after a slight modification) work? Which features of the free group are really necessary here?

Comment: I am not sure how easily this would go beyond virtually free.  Maybe for nice enough subgroups of free products.  You need to have good control over sewing in loops. Maybe mccammond -wise perimeter conditions help.