# Conjugates and infinite index subgroups of free groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, free-groups

Here I am asking for an analogue of [Generating infinite index subgroups of a free group](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191855/generating-infinite-index-subgroups-of-a-free-group)

Let $F$ be a nonabelian finitely generated free group, let $H \leq F$ be a finitely generated subgroup of infinite index, and let $x \in F$. Must there be some $y \in F$ such that $[F : \langle H, yxy^{-1}\rangle] =\infty$ ?

Comment: This can be answered the same way as your other one. Choose y to not be readable at the base and not cancel too much of x.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The  proof is like before.  Let $\Gamma$ be the Stallings graph for $H$. Choose a word $w$ labeling a path from the base point to a vertex q where some letter or its inverse, call it a, cannot be read.  If $axa^{-1}$ is reduced, then by sowing an edge a at q followed by x as a loop, we obtain a Stallings graph of an infinite index subgroup containing H and $yxy^{-1}$ where $y=wa$. Else choose b different than a or its inverse and sow at q a pair of edges labeled ab followed by $x$ as a loop. This results in a Stallings graph of an infinite index subgroup containing  H and $yxy^{-1}$ with y=wab.

Comment: And how do we know that after sowing the index does not become finite? What letter cannot be read after sowing?

Comment: We may assume that x has at least 2 letters.  Otherwise replace it by $cxc^{-1}$ for some other letter $c$. But if x has more than one letter then the loop I sowed in labeled by x has missing letters at the end point of the first edge.

Comment: @Pablo, a finite Stallings graph represents an infinite-index subgroup iff some vertex has less than maximal degree.

Comment: @HJRW To which nonfree groups does this generalize?

Comment: It generalizes to hyperbolic groups and quasiconvex subgroups.